# Setting up Postfix when hosting multiple domains

Tags: postfix, installation, fqdn

I only know enough Ubuntu to be dangerous, so I could use some advice.

I'm using Linode to host a couple of domains.  Let's call them:

www.company.com
www.product.com
dev.product.com

The server's FDQN is hq.company.com, and all of the mail is routed to Google Apps.

So far everything is working great.  I've got Apache installed and it is responding for all three sites.  me@company.com works as well.

What I'm trying to do now is set up Postfix so I can have *@product.com forwarded to support@company.com.  (Note: Open to smarter ideas, btw)

I'm running the Postfix package configuration and it is asking for my FQDN.  This is where I'm stuck.  Do I use hq.company.com?  I'm very fuzzy on the concept of FQDN's, especially if I'm hosting multiple domains.  Any tips will be appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution would be to just host all the mail domains with Google Apps. You can define alias domains under the same Google Apps account (so support@{company.com,product.com,dev.product.com} would all go to the "support" mailbox).

If you really want to use an external [mail forwarder](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#forwarding), you don't want to set either the source and destination domains as Postfix's FQDN, because it will treat it as a local destination. Your Postfix configuration should look something like this:

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain
virtual_alias_domains = product.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

/etc/postfix/virtual:

```
@product.com    support@mycompany.com
```

Run `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` whenever this file has been modified.

Comment: Hmm.. I think I might just take your advice and use Google Apps.  I forgot you can make aliases, so I won't have to pay for a business account.  Thanks for the suggestion!